# Куда уходит пользователь с сайта ?

Tags: javascript

Как узнать куда пошел пользователь с моего сайта ?

Comment: `Google`, перелогинтесь.

Comment: Пытать его.

Comment: Мне тоже интересно - если он сразу за пивом пойдёт, то эта информация очень бы пригодилась.

Comment: пытать?

    setInterval(function() {
      var tuda = prompt('ti kuda????');
      // :D
    });

Comment: вы смеетесь, а ведь реально есть такое событие в js, но мне впадлу его писать, ТС пользуйся гуглом!

Comment: Шутки шутите ?

Comment: @johniek_comp, ага, наверное, его обработчик выглядит примерно так:

    on_куда_пошел_юзер()

Comment: Да, и правду есть. Но оно !!! не работает почти во всех браузерах, по моему кроме IE :)

Comment: onbeforeunload - то про что я говорил.

Comment: onbeforeunload поддерживается во [всех](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) браузерах, но получить из него информацию куда пошёл пользователь вы не можете.

Answer (score 2):

Никак

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам следует сделать внешние ссылки в формате

```
   www.vashsite.ru/perehod.php?url=www.vneshayassilka
```

И когда юзер нажимает на сайте на внешнюю ссылку, то он сначала обращается к скрипту perehod.php , который обрабатывает url и посылает пользователя дальше.

Кстати, наверное JS вам понадобится для того, чтобы вызывать этот скрипт ;)
Остальное дело php :D

Comment: Этот вариант хорош, но он требует вмешательства в работу уже давно окопавшихся ссылок. Например РСЯ и Адсены и другие некоторые партнерки запрещают модифицировать их коды.

Answer (score 0):

[onbeforeunload](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror) - поправочка: работает 100% в Mozilla, в **Chrome && Opera - НЕ РАБОТАЕТ**.

Answer (score -1):

разве что через жквери контролировать все элементы <a>.
на событие клик узнаем  что за ссылка

```
$('a').each(function(){
     $(this).click(function(){
           alert($(this).attr('href'));
     });
});
```

Comment: Вопрос-то был про то, куда пользователь уходит с сайта, а не про "на какую ссылку пользователь нажал" :)
То, о чём спрашивал ТС, отследить невозможно

Comment: а тоесть нажав на ссылку которая ведет на другой сайт пользователь не уйдет с сайта чтоли?

Comment: как-бы можно просто ввести url не нажимая на ссылку, не?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, ну да, именно про это я и говорил :)

Comment: так никто и не спорит что можно, но как будто пользователь и через ссылку на сайте не может уйти